# how to build a jar with maven for a specific OS?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tensorflow, bytecode

I am using maven for Eclipse to build a jar that will run on a remote server. My system is running OS X, the server is running CestOS. 
For the project I need [tensorflow library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/tensorflow/0.9.0-1.2). Maven successfully resolves dependencies so I am able to run the project locally. However, on the server I am getting error that tensorflow library is not there because by default maven includes only macosx version. How can I force maven to substitute macosx version of tensorflow by the linux version during build?

TensorFlow java libraries for different platforms can be found [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tensorflow/0.9.0-1.2/).

P.S. I already tried adding a dependency in pom with the system scope pointing to jar.

Comment: Did you try considering Maven profiles?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use profiles but I was only able to find info on how to activate specific profile based on current OS. I couldn`t find how to create profile that will build a jar for a different OS.

Comment: Can you snapshot the error? Or can can you include the error log here?

Comment: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnitensorflow in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:654)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:492)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:409)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tensorflow.<clinit>(tensorflow.java:10)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ...

Comment: Have you had a chance to try the solutions here proposed?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your POM:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
    <artifactId>tensorflow</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0-1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
    <artifactId>tensorflow</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0-1.2</version>
    <classifier>linux-x86_64</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Or `linux-x86` instead, if your server is 32-bit.

Of course, defining a conditional dependency with profiles would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the jar names on the page you linked, the difference between the MacOs and Linux versions lies in the text after the `version` part on the jar name.

That is called the `classifier` (see [Maven coordinates](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates#Maven_Coordinates)) and is an optional coordinate that gives an additional differentiation after the artifact version.

As already suggested by [nandsito](/a/40536880/3127111), and to expand on its answer, try this (untested, let me know and I'll update):

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>osx</id>
         
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
                <artifactId>tensorflow</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.0-1.2</version>
                <classifier>macosx-x86_64</classifier>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        
    </profile>
    
    <profile>
        <id>linux</id>
        
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
                <artifactId>tensorflow</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.0-1.2</version>
                <classifier>linux-x86_64</classifier>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

    </profile>

</profiles>
```

And remove all the related `<dependency>` nodes elsewere in your POM (so that without the `<profiles>` part there would be no dependency for `tensorflow`).

After this change you'll necessarily have to specify a profile each time (as there will be no tensorflow dependency in the POM): when preparing the package on MacOs `mvn clean package -Pmacos` and when preparing the package on Centos `mvn clean package -Plinux`

Eclipse allows you to set a list of active profiles under `Project properties` > `Maven` (you can get to this window by right-clicking on the project folder in the `Project explorer`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to setup a build system such as Jenkins and have configuration for each target environment/platform. When building for Linux, configure the build system to run this command `mvn clean package -Djavacpp.platform=linux-x86_64`, the key point here is the parameter `-Djavacpp.platform`, change it according to your target platform.